# How do I get my server-side Joi validation to work properly with redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, redux, redux-form

I have Joi validation on my back-end express server. I am able to get the validation messages from the backend into a redux errors state object, however how do I properly set this redux object state up to show the messages on the front end with redux-form correctly. Especially when the errors toggle back and forth from something such as: "name is required" to "name must be at least 2 characters"

I have tried doing what the redux-form docs say by importing SubmissionError and throwing a new SubmissionError object when the validation error occurs.

It looks like this sits in the callback function that is passed to redux-forms own this.props.handleSubmit method.

However in my current code I am getting a "react-dom.development.js:57 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." Error now,

Component where the Input component sits.

```
class WorkoutNew extends React.Component {
  onSubmit = formValues => {

    this.props.createWorkout(formValues, this.props.history);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="title is-3">Create a workout</h1>
        <SingleForm onSubmit={this.onSubmit} form="newWorkout" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ errors }) => {
  return { errors };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { createWorkout }
)(withRouter(WorkoutNew));
```

Re-used single input form component. I pass in form="value" as props to set each use of this form to have a unique form value.

```
class SingleForm extends React.Component {
  onSubmit = formValues => {
    console.log("Form Values", formValues);
    console.log("PROPS", this.props);

    if (formValues) {
      throw new SubmissionError({
        name: this.props.errors
      });
    }

    this.props.onSubmit(formValues);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
          <Field label="Name" name="name" type="text" component={InputField} />
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="button is-primary is-large"
            style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ errors }) => {
  return { errors };
};

export default reduxForm({})(connect(mapStateToProps)(SingleForm));
```

Here I pass in an empty object because I user this component multiple times, I pass the form: 'value' as props.

My action creator.

```
export const createWorkout = (formValues, history) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/workouts", formValues)
    .then(res => {
      history.push("/workouts");
      // Push back to workouts page
    })
    .catch(err => dispatch({ type: GET_ERRORS, payload: err.response.data }));
};
```

What I would like to happen is that when I submit my input it shows the server-side validation error under the input. These errors are being properly fetched into my redux errors object as well.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping ephemeral state in redux is considered bad practice, I would suggest using [Formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/) to keep all form logic within your component, you will also find that the way Formik handles submissions allows setting errors for each field using the Formik bag. Alternatively, I would suggest you consider using [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) for sync client-side validation, the API is almost exactly like [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi). As stated on the Joi repo, you should not use Joi for client-side validation as this lib was developed with nodeJS in mind.

Comment: What do you mean by "Keeping ephemeral state in redux is bad practice?" Thank you for the suggestions also!

Comment: This goes back to the principle that [global variables are bad](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad), Redux is a verbose and structured global state, and according to Dan Abramov (creator) you should only keep state that is relevant to the whole application or that needs to be processed in complex ways. in short, if you can use the local state, use the local state, don't enforce the mentality of making everything globally accessible